# ActionNext does not work with multiline EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have multiple multi-line EditText in my layout with ImeOptions set to ActionNext. But the android keypad does not show Next button. When I remove textMultiLine from inputType, then Next button appears.
How to achieve it with multiline EditText?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using multiple multi-line edit texts in your layout, in this case the action next will not work because this button will work as the enter button to enter text in new line .